# Enlarging ImageSlider on Tap in Swift iOS

Tags: uiimageview, slider, swift2, ios8.3

I want to have 3 ImageSliders stack on top of each other, not overlay, like 3 sliders one on top, one in the middle, and one at the bottom. When you tap on one, it resizes to 30% larger in Height and Width, once you tap another one, the current one resizes back to 30% smaller and the new one which got tapped enlarges 30% in size. How can I make such thing in Swift ? I tried to google some solution but haven't find any tutorial or answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated, but you can experiment with the following API which can be used on any view, including the `UISlider`.

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
```

This can also be animated by including it into a `UIView` animation block (see documentation about `animateWithDuration`).